# kallsyms_lookup_name undefined error in 5.10.0-kali7-amd64

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel

I'm trying to make a basic kernel hook which happens to use kallsyms_lookup_name, but each time i try to compile the module i get `modpost: "kallsyms_lookup_name" [<path to .ko>] undefined!`

I have `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")` in my module, in `/proc/kallsyms` i found `T kallsyms_lookup_name`, but in `/lib/modules/<kernel>/build/Module.symvers` i couldn't find it. So is the symbol not exported and if not, what do I do to export it?

I'm pretty new to kernel programming.

Comment: It's not exported in newer kernels due to the security issues it causes. When I practiced hooking, I used an Ubuntu 16 or 18 iirc.

Comment: Is there a way to export it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use it cause it's not exported by the latest kernels. You always can build your own kernel, just undo these changes - [git patch](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200221114404.14641-4-will@kernel.org/). However, that's not good for production :)